# Byte data type in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, swift2

I remember there being a Byte data type in Swift, but I haven't done any Swift programming in about six months.

Now when I write in an iOS playground:

```swift
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
var str = [Byte]
```

I get an error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Byte'`

I've been googling around and can't find any documentation on the Byte data type, and yet I'm pretty sure I've used it before.

What's going on?

Comment: maybe you meant `RawByte`?

Comment: It always helps to reduce code to a minimal example demonstrating the problem: `var x : Byte` in a Playground produces the error message `error: use of undeclared type 'Byte'; did you mean to use 'UInt8'?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, you can not use this type of data, in fact it was the other name of an 8-bit `UInt8` type and is now you have to use `UInt8`

From `MacTypes.h`:

> ```
> ...
> /*********************************************************************************
>
>  Old names for types
>
> *********************************************************************************/
> typedef UInt8 Byte;
> ...
> ```

It's old name for `UInt8` type